# Issue in PHP Ajax Execution Order

Tags: php, ajax

I do have below index.php and operatora.php as follows. I suspect that this issue should be due to the order of execution because when I add the `loadChart()` function to `index.php` inside the `head` I can see the graphs. I don't need to add the loachart() function to index.php. Because these graphs change from time to time based on the operator. So I need to keep them in the relevant php file. Can someone show me what was the issue of my code?

Below is the index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Operator Bypass Portal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

    <style>
        .wrapper {
            display: flex;
        }

        .sidebar {
            width: 250px;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #7F00FF;
            color: black;
        }

        .main_content {
            flex: 1;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
          function loadChart() {
              //If I add the content here I can see the graphs
          }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    session_start();

    // Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect to the login page
    if (!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true) {
        header("location: login.php");
        exit;
    }

    $connect = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "System_Monitor");
    $query = "SELECT user_type, operator FROM BypassPortal_OP_users where id='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "' order by id asc";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    ?>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <h2 style="font-family: Verdana;">Portal</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadContent('home.php')"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                <?php
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    if (strstr($row["operator"], "SLT")) {
                        echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadContent(\'operatora.php\')"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Operator - A</a></li>';
                        echo '<li><a href="logout.php"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Logout</a></li>';
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main_content">
            <!-- The content will be loaded here dynamically -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    function loadDefaultContent() {
        var mainContent = document.querySelector(".main_content");
        var loader = '<div class="loader">Loading...</div>';
        mainContent.innerHTML = loader;

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", 'home.php', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                mainContent.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }

    // Call the function to load the default content
    loadDefaultContent();

   function loadContent(content) {
       var mainContent = document.querySelector(".main_content");
       var loader = '<div class="loader">Loading...</div>';
       mainContent.innerHTML = loader;

       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.open("GET", content, true);
       xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            mainContent.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            loadChart();
        } else {
            console.error("Error loading content: " + xhr.status);
        }
    }
};
       xhr.send();
     }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the operatora.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Operator - A</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <style>
        .grid-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
            grid-gap: 20px;
        }
        .grid-item {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Operator - A</h2>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item">
            <canvas id="graph1"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <canvas id="graph2"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <canvas id="graph3"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <canvas id="graph4"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        // Sample data for the bar chart
        var data = {
            labels: ["Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Graph 1",
                    data: [30, 50, 20],
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    borderWidth: 1
                }
            ]
        };

        // Function to create and display the charts
        function loadChart() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('graph1').getContext('2d');

            // Create the bar chart using Chart.js
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: data,
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        // Call the function to load and display the charts
        loadChart();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are loading the contents of `operatora.php` into a `div`, so `operatora.php` must not contain a whole html document but only the elements you want inside the `div` (probably everything that's in the `<body>` right now).
2. Function `loadDefaultContent()` seems to be completely redundant, you can use function `loadContent()` instead.
3. Scripts included inside the returned HTML from an ajax request will not be evaluated implicitly for security reasons. You can `eval` them explicitly, but that's not the best overall design. However, this is how it's done:

```
    function loadContent(content) {
        var mainContent = document.querySelector(".main_content");
        var loader = '<div class="loader">Loading...</div>';
        mainContent.innerHTML = loader;

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", content, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    mainContent.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                    const scripts = mainContent.getElementsByTagName("script");
                    for (const script of scripts) {
                        console.log(eval(script.innerHTML));
                    }
                } else {
                    console.error("Error loading content: " + xhr.status);
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
```

4. You should not return a function in `operatora.php` to avoid declaring functions all over again. Simply do what you have to do right inside the `<script>` block. This is the `operatora.php` I've tested with:

```
    <h2>Operator - A</h2>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item">
            <canvas id="graph1"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <canvas id="graph2"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <canvas id="graph3"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <canvas id="graph4"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        // Sample data for the bar chart
        var data = {
            labels: ["Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Graph 1",
                    data: [30, 50, 20],
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    borderWidth: 1
                }
            ]
        };

        var ctx = document.getElementById('graph1').getContext('2d');

        // Create the bar chart using Chart.js
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: data,
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

5. For reference, this is the `index.php` I've used for testing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Operator Bypass Portal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

    <style>
        .wrapper {
            display: flex;
        }

        .sidebar {
            width: 250px;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #7F00FF;
            color: black;
        }

        .main_content {
            flex: 1;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <h2 style="font-family: Verdana;">Portal</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadContent('home.php')"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadContent('operatora.php')"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Operator - A</a></li>';
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main_content">
            <!-- The content will be loaded here dynamically -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    // Call the function to load the default content
    loadContent('home.php')

    function loadContent(content) {
        var mainContent = document.querySelector(".main_content");
        var loader = '<div class="loader">Loading...</div>';
        mainContent.innerHTML = loader;

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", content, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    mainContent.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                    const scripts = mainContent.getElementsByTagName("script");
                    for (const script of scripts) {
                        console.log(eval(script.innerHTML));
                    }
                } else {
                    console.error("Error loading content: " + xhr.status);
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

6. Since you didn't provide `home.php` I've used a copy of `operatora.php` with random `data`.

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome!